# Start Process after Enviroment.Exit

Tags: c#, process

My Problem: I want to add a restart function, this would be no problem, but I need to start it after I closed the programm, because there can be only one instance of the programm. How do I somehow start a process (itself) after I made Enviroment.Exit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was, thanks to ckuri (https://stackoverflow.com/users/7565574/ckuri) :

"You obviously have some code that checks if an instance is already running, and if one is running the start of current app gets aborted. One solution for the restart issue would be to start the new process with an argument stating to skip the instance check."

Comment: That’s not really a clean solution as it depends on if the application gets killed by the OS within 50ms. So this could fail on slow machines or if the machine is under full load.

Comment: What do you recommend to do?

Comment: You obviously have some code that checks if an instance is already running, and if one is running the start of current app gets aborted. One solution for the restart issue would be to start the new process with an argument stating to skip the instance check.

Comment: The other solution is about how you check if an instance is running. Often this is done by creating a unique global mutex, e.g. `new Mutex(true, "Global/some-guid/here")`. As there can only be one system-global mutex of the same name, if you start a second instance it can’t create a second mutex as there can only be one, and therefore knows there is already an instance running and exits. So for the restart issue, you would first release your global mutex, start the new instance (which would find no mutex and thus not exit) and close yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, and if this is a Windows Forms application. This might help you:

[Application.Restart Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.restart?view=net-5.0)

It's been around for ever, and they put it back in to .net Core 3.0

- .NET 5.0
- .NET Core 3.0, 3.1
- .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8

> Shuts down the application and starts a new instance immediately.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The most common reason for calling Restart is to start a new version
> of the application that you have downloaded through ClickOnce using
> the Update or UpdateAsync method.
>
> Applications are restarted in the context in which they were initially
> run. If your application was started using a URL pointing directly to
> the application's main executable file, it will be restarted using the
> same URL. If your application is a ClickOnce application, it will be
> restarted using ClickOnce.
>
> If your application was originally supplied command-line options when
> it first executed, Restart will launch the application again with the
> same options.

Comment: The documentation states that it throws a NotSupportedException if it’s not a Windows Forms application. Does it work for other application types?

Comment: @ckuri no, and i was actually meant to state that :) thanks for reminding me

Comment: It is sadly a WPF .

Answer (score 0):

You should not do `Environment.Exit`, just think about other running threads?
You can use the below code to restart.

```
static void RestartProcess(int processId, string processName )
{
    Process process = null;
    try
    {
        process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        Application.Exit();
        //Or you can use process.WaitForExit(1000);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
    
    }
    Process.Start(processName);
}
```

Comment: I need to do envirmoent.Exit. The programm checks at the beginning if it is already running, if yes then it closes it self again. Application.Exit() also doesnt work.

Comment: try `process.WaitForExit(1000);` you can set the time accordingly. I have mentioned in my code